# ggplot scientific axis labels - scale values by 1e6 and format "E-06"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want scientific x axis labels. so far so good. But I want all of them in E-06 format and I don't know how.

I tried with this:
`scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE))`

But I don't know how to force it in the E-06 format

[image: Graph]

I formatted the data in the text file already in the right format.

[image: E-06]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to scale your values by 1e6 and add a suffix "E-06" instead of using scientific notation? If so, you could use the function `scales::label_number()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(Vol06) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(seq_along(Vol06), Vol06)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::label_number(scale = 1e6, suffix = "E-06"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

where

```r
Vol06 <- c(
  -12.500e-06,
  7.520e-06,
  17.200e-06,
  22.600e-06,
  22.500e-06,
  39.200e-06,
  42.500e-06,
  51.000e-06,
  47.500e-06,
  51.300e-06,
  63.300e-06,
  73.800e-06,
  80.400e-06,
  83.600e-06,
  91.700e-06,
  96.200e-06,
  92.800e-06,
  92.500e-06,
  91.600e-06,
  92.400e-06,
  90.500e-06,
  84.900e-06,
  90.000e-06,
  94.900e-06,
  92.700e-06,
  89.300e-06,
  92.500e-06,
  90.800e-06,
  90.400e-06,
  88.400e-06,
  89.600e-06,
  86.700e-06,
  75.100e-06,
  72.300e-06,
  73.600e-06,
  74.500e-06,
  76.100e-06
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Create plot
ggplot(data = data.frame(x, y), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = function(x) sprintf("%1.1e", signif(x, digits = 2))) +
  labs(x = "X-axis label (E-06)")
```